# Prove the following expression.

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I have to prove
$$
\operatorname{U}\left(a,\frac{1}{2};x^2\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(a\right)}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\Gamma\left(a+\frac{n}{2}\right)}{n!}(-2x)^n}
$$
**My Attempt**:
$$
\operatorname{U}\left(a,\frac{1}{2};x^2\right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^\infty{e^{-x^2t}t^{a-1}(1+t)^{-a-\frac{1}{2}}dt}\\
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^\infty{\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-x^2t)^n}{n!}}\right)t^{a-1}(1+t)^{-a-\frac{1}{2}}dt}\\
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}\int_0^\infty {t^{a+n-1}\left(\frac{1}{1+t}\right)^{a+\frac{1}{2}}dt}}\\
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}\frac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}{\Gamma\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}}\\
=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)\Gamma\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{\Gamma(a+n)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)}{n!}(-x^2)^n}
$$
How do I proceed further, please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, what's the function U?

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera. Kummer hypergeometric function $\, _1F_1\left(a;\frac{1}{2};x^2\right)$

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera Kummer's function of second kind

Comment: Please edit the title so it gives the reader some idea of what kind of question this is.